# Is there a way to pass a method into another method in c# and what's the best way to do it?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, .net-standard

I'm trying to keep my code dry. I have 5 methods that have the same bulk of code but I don't want the write them all multiple times. Below are 2 sample methods. I want to know how I can consolidate it into 1 generic method. Is that the best way to do it?

```
public async Task<PlaylistListResponse> GetPlaylistsFromChannel(string channelID, bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    string barrelURL = "GetPlaylistsFromChannel" + channelID.Trim();
    PlaylistListResponse results = default;

    if(forceRefresh != true)
    {
        results = GetCached<PlaylistListResponse>(barrelURL);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if (object.Equals(results, default(PlaylistListResponse)))
            {
                var playlistFromChannelRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("id");
                playlistFromChannelRequest.ChannelId = channelID;
                playlistFromChannelRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                results = await playlistFromChannelRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                Barrel.Current.Add(barrelURL, results, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
            }

            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
    }

    return results;
}

public async Task<PlaylistListResponse> GetPlaylistsFromChannel(string channelID, bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    string barrelURL = "GetPlaylistsFromChannel" + channelID.Trim();
    PlaylistListResponse results = default;

    if (forceRefresh != true)
    {
        results = GetCached<PlaylistListResponse>(barrelURL);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if (object.Equals(results, default(PlaylistListResponse)))
            {
                var videosFromPlaylistRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                videosFromPlaylistRequest.PlaylistId = playlistID;
                videosFromPlaylistRequest.MaxResults = 50;

                results = await videosFromPlaylistRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                Barrel.Current.Add(barrelURL, results, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
            }

            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

I've tried creating a generic method but can't find a way to make changes to it as I don't want a multitude of `if` statements.

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string barrelURL, int days = 7, bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    results = default(T);

    if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        results = Barrel.Current.Get<T>(barrelURL);

    if (!forceRefresh && !Barrel.Current.IsExpired(barrelURL))
        results = Barrel.Current.Get<T>(barrelURL);

    try
    {
        if (object.Equals(results, default(T)))
        {
            //myMethodsCode??
            Barrel.Current.Add(barrelURL, results, TimeSpan.FromDays(days));
        }

        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Unable to get information from server {ex}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution to this problem would be to create a generic method and pass delegates that represent differing parts into it.

```
public async Task<T> GetFromChannel<T>(
    string channelID,
    Func<Task<T>> resultGetter,
    bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    string barrelURL = "GetPlaylistsFromChannel" + channelID.Trim();
    T results = default;

    if (forceRefresh != true)
    {
        results = GetCached<T>(barrelURL);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if (object.Equals(results, default(T)))
            {
                results = await resultGetter();
                Barrel.Current.Add(barrelURL, results, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
            }

            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

And then you can insert the differing parts using other methods or lambda exressions, for example:

```
public Task<PlaylistListResponse> GetPlaylistsFromChannel(
    string channelID,
    bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    return GetFromChannel<PlaylistListResponse>(
        channelID,
        async () =>
        {
            var videosFromPlaylistRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
            videosFromPlaylistRequest.PlaylistId = playlistID;
            videosFromPlaylistRequest.MaxResults = 50;

            return await videosFromPlaylistRequest.ExecuteAsync();
        },
        forceRefresh);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: @RyanGaudion if you mean efficient as in speed and/or memory efficiency, then I don't really know. It's obviously a little less efficient than directly writing 5 different methods, because it involves more method calls and for every delegate there's an instance that has to be allocated. But I would say that it's a pretty insignificant change of speed and memory. If you mean efficient from the maintainability point of view (DRY etc.) then it's subjective, but as for me, it's pretty maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for this, it really helped!

Comment: Please can you review my original question. If it needs improving then please can you suggest how to improve it, if not please can you upvote it. Thank you

Comment: @RyanGaudion I've fixed code formatting in your question. Other than that, it's ok I guess :)